# document not defined error in a client component in beta version

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, quill

I have the following component in `NextJs` version `13 (Beta)`.

I have marked it to be a `client` component. Yet I get the following error.

> Uncaught Error: document is not defined

I can call something like `document.location` inside `useEffect`, no issues.

The issue comes when I call `document` inside the `return` block.

I am not the one doing it. It is the external dependency component that calls document.

Thus not within my control. How can I address this?

It is throwing the `document is not defined` error due to the `ReactQuill` component.

This component is at /app/editor/page.tsx

```
'use client'
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import ReactQuill from 'react-quill';

const Editor = ({ placeholder }) => {
  // no issues with using hooks
  const [editorHtml, setEditorHtml] = useState('');
  const [theme, setTheme] = useState('snow');

  useEffect(() => {
    // no issues here
    console.log(document.location.href)
  })

  return (
    <div>
    {/* somewhere inside this component there is a call to document causing issue */}
    {/* issue is with the quill dependency that has a call to document */}
    {/* even adding checks like document !== 'undefined' results in same error*/}
      <ReactQuill
        theme={theme}
        value={editorHtml}
        modules={Editor.modules}
        formats={Editor.formats}
        bounds={'.app'}
        placeholder={placeholder}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Editor;
```